# Replace the parameter in URL & refresh the page

Tags: javascript, url

My Default URL will be like

```
http://localhost:4444/index.html?file=sample
```

And I have a drop down list with various filenames, I want to replace the parameter `sample` by clicking drop down list.
For each and every change the URL should be altered with existing parameter.

I Tried with following,

```
location.href = location.href + "filename" ;
```

But it won't replace the filename.

Comment: location.href = location.href.replace(/sample/,"filename")

Comment: @Reeno this could be fine, but for next file selection...?

Comment: Do you want to replace `?file=sample`?

Comment: I want to replace sample to filename1 & filename1 to filename2 & .....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is:

```
location.href = location.origin + location.pathname + '?file=filename';
```

But this would only work when you have one parameter after the `?`. If you have more - you'd need to parse them and re-apply.

Comment: `location.host` is without protocol, you could use `location.origin` (`http://example.com` instead of `example.com`)

Comment: @SamvanKampen I missed that! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 21):

Welcome to 2018, you can now [mostly](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams) use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to handle the parsing and replacing you get

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
params.set('file', 'sample');
window.location.search = params.toString();
```

[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) will replace or add the parameter to the query string as needed.

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

```
location.search = location.search.replace(/file=[^&$]*/i, 'file=filename');
```

`location.search` property holds only the *query* part of the URL so you don't have to worry that any other parts of the url (e.g. domain or hash) will be modified.
Also, the regex will replace only the `file` parameter. It is useful when you'll have some other parameters in *query*.

Comment: this is actually a really elegant way as it will reload automatically and there is no need to work with the entire URL.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted @matewka answer to be more robust by also working when there are no existing params in `window.location.search`

```
var filename = 'myFilename.csv';

var paramName = 'file';
var newParam = paramName + '=' + filename;
if(window.location.search){
  var regex = new RegExp(paramName + '=[^&$]*', 'i');
  window.location.search = window.location.search.replace(regex, newParam);
}else{
  window.location.search = newParam;
}
```